# PHP method for replacing a certain "index" in a string (like the 3rd character for instance) with another string

Tags: php

Say I hate the word "hat". I want a function that would work something like `strreplace("hat", 1, "o")` therefore changing it into `hot` instead of `hat`.

Is there a way to do this with a function? Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: You have to write your own :)

Comment: `$foo = 'hat'; $foo[1] = 'o';`

Comment: That only works for single characters, not for strings.

Comment: substr_replace was what I was looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: I did not know about that function, good you found your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeChar($string,$newchar,$pos){
  $string[$pos] = $newchar;
  return $string;
}

echo changeChar("Logs","L",2);
```

Would echo "LoLs"

```
Logs
0123 <position (g is the 2nd character ;)
```

insert this just below the first line if you want the first character to be the 1st not 0th:

```
$pos = $pos + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function myReplacing($theString, $theCharacter, $thePosition)
{
    return substr_replace($theString, $theCharacter, $thePosition, 1);
}

$a = "test";
$a = myReplacing($a, "u", 1);
echo $a;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is str_replace(). See here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

e.g.

```
echo str_replace("a", "o", "hat");
// outputs 'hot'
```